# Set Field from parent from child's iframe

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that opens up a search page that shows the results in an iframe.  Upon selection of a particular search result, I want to send a value from the search page's iframe to the opening page and close the search page. How do I do this?

Comment: you can use form tag in iframe and submit the page  on selection of a result on search page

Comment: Never mind:  Got it: parent.opener.document.getElementById("street1").value = street1;

Comment: cool, now close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
parent.opener.document.getElementById("street1").value = street1;
```